# WPF Datagrid posts empty item to ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm using a WPF Datagrid bound to an observable collection that interfaces with a generic EF repository.  When I try to create a new item, the datagrid tries to add a new item with empty fields.  Since one of the fields is a key, the add fails with a non-null exception.  Unfortunately, the user hasn't even had the opportunity to provide all the new values before the add takes place.  How can I stop the Datagrid from adding the new item to the collection until the edits are complete (ie the user has entered all the fields)?

Comment: why dont you just keep it in memory until it is ready to be saved?

Comment: that's exactly what I'd like the Datagrid to do until the user finishes editing the entire row.  Instead it's submitting a item with null values to the collection.

Comment: The WPF data grid has transaction semantics on it that you can use to override add/edit and marshall completed transactions to the EF